# Why can VPS use same ip for different users

Tags: vps

First I believe that any VPS server will share an IP among many users, since that the number of IP address is limited. So my question is: for example user A and user B share one IP, and they both created an HTTP server, so why other users type the IP address in Browser, how the VPS know which http server should be used?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

VPS's cannot share the same IP, they must have unique IPv4 or IPv6 addresses. With shared hosting you use virtual hosts to determine the site by its domain name.

Comment: If so, the VPS provider needs lots of IP, such as it has 1 million users, so that it also need 1 million different IPs? It's unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility would be the Host-Header, which allows http servers to depach requests to different sites that share the same ip address. More information can be found at the [http spec - 14.23 Host](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).